# Is it possible to combine the User Notifications IOS functionality with the AVAudiosessions functionality to create an Alarm app using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am currently learning IOS development and am creating an alarm app. I have seen prior posts on here explaining how Apps such as Alarmy use AVAudiosessions and AVAudioplayer to implement their alarm functionality, but I am not seeing how this is possible.

The prior posts I speak of do not handle the correct scheduling of the AVAudioplayer so that it works as an alarm.

I have a current implementation that just uses user notifications, but this is not very powerful since it does not work if the phone is on silent mode, and they are just short notifications that do not make a good alarm.

`import UIKit

import UserNotifications

import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
var alarms = [Date]()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()   
@IBOutlet weak var alarmTimePicker: UIDatePicker!



@IBAction func setAlarm(_ sender: Any) {

    print("hit button")

    let selectedTime = alarmTimePicker.date

    

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "ALERT"

    content.body = "It is your scheduled time."

    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named:UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "alarm.wav"))

    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute],from: selectedTime)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content:content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error")
        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.alarms.append(selectedTime)
                self.createAlert(withTitle: "Alarm Set for \(selectedTime)", andDescription: "Your alarm is set for \(self.alarms)")
            }
        }
    }
}
func createAlert(withTitle title:String,andDescription description: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: description, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok" , style: .default) {
        _ in print("You set an alert")

    }

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,willPresent notification: UNNotification,withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping(UNNotificationPresentationOptions)-> Void){

    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])   

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    

  

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

}`

I have tried setting up the alarm using AVAudiosessions, but it does not seem possible to have it work with the User notifications